# Position and Scale resetting on render

Tags: rendering, scale

I have an FBX model I'm using in blender. I've worked with FBX before in blender with no problems. But every time I change the position, size,  or pose of this one it resets as soon as I render an image, going back to the pose, size and position it was before I changed it. I've tried numerous fixes from the web but nothing is helping. I've never had this problem with any other model FBX,  obj,  blend, or any other. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: You probably have a keyframe (animation) on some part or all of your mesh. This gets reset to the beginning everytime. Just find your keyframes and delete them.

Comment: There are no keyframes

Comment: Would it work if I added a keyframe thats the position I want it on?

Comment: Would be easier if you can share a link to your blend, or at least provide some screenshots

Comment: I fixed it,  added how as an answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this problem I fixed it by first make sure you have no keyframes. If there are none and your object still resets position on render position your object how you want it than add that position as a keyframe.